# display constraints of Certain table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to know how to display all constraints of a certain table(all columns) by the SELECT statement in PostgreSQL. I tried this code:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.referential_constraints;
```

Actually, I want the primary keys and foreign keys of the tables

Answer (score 0):

Following should do the trick. Just change **table-name-goes-here** with your table name.

```
SELECT
    tc.table_schema, tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name, 
    ccu.table_schema AS foreign_table_schema,
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name 
FROM 
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type in ('PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY') 
AND tc.table_name='table-name-goes-here';
```